# How can you Simplify formula comparing two cells in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two sets of data I would like to compare to see if they match. I like a good  old `=G7=AZ7`, who doesn't. The problem I have is that sometimes my first table (`G7`) is blank when my second table is `0` (`AZ7`) and they don't equal one another. Simply doing `=G7-AZ7` gives me an error. So as you see in the formula below I over complicated things, and wanted the end result to be either `0` or `1`.

Do you know a way to simplify this?

```
=IF(AND(G7="",AZ7="0"),"0",IF(IFERROR(G7-AZ7,1)=1,1,IF(ABS(G7-AZ7)>0,1,0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

use EXACT(), it will see the blank as not equal to `0`:

```
=--EXACT(G7,AZ7)
```

[image]